# How do the "da-" and "wo-" prefixes work?

Tags: adverb, prefix, conjunction

I don't completely understand the da- and wo- compound words. I have an idea of what they are and what they do but I'm not completely sure how they work and how to use them.

If you don't know what I mean I'm talking about the words like ***daher, dahin, davon, daraus***, etc. Here are some examples taken from an article in the Spiegel App.

> "Das Problem ist der Begriff Karriere und alles, was **damit** verbunden ist."

Seeing *damit* in this sentence, I'm thinking that it means 'with that'. Another sentence from the same article.

> "**Darauf** haben Frauen keine Lust."

*Darauf* seems to mean something akin to 'about that' or 'for that'. Again, I'm just guessing based on the context.

I'm not going to post all the da- words (and I haven't found any wo- words in this article) but I hope you get what I'm asking.

Comment: @falkb: I'm a she ;_;

Comment: In case it helps: Many of these words have English cognates that start with *there/where* instead of *da/wo* and end with the cognates of the respective prepositions. E.g. *therein* is the cognate of *darin* and *wherefrom* of *wovon*. Of course the precise use of these words has diverged a bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general you use *da-* compounds to talk about something you've already mentioned instead of using the complete noun or using prep + *es*. That's why "wir sprechen über es" has <2000 Google hits while "wir sprechen darüber" has >200,000.

> Heute benötigt ihr dieses Buch. Wir sprechen darüber.
>
> Ich kann das Handy nicht finden. Ich suche danach.

In these sentences you already know the people need that book and I can't find my keys, so instead of completely restating the noun you can refer to it with a *da-* compound.

*Wo-* compounds are a bit different from *da-* compounds. You use them where in English you'd say "What/where .... [prep] (Where are you coming from, What's that made of).

> Wofür ist das denn? Ich brauche es, um mein Handy zu finden.
>
> Worüber sprecht ihr? Übers neue Buch.

Imagine you're saying "What for is that?" or "What about are you all talking", a word order some people use in English in formal contexts, but you put the question word and preposition into one word.

Notes:

1. *Da-/Wo-* compounds cannot be used for people or animals
2. *Da-/Wo-* compounds cannot be used for *außer*, *ohne*, *seit*, *gegenüber*, uncommon prepositions  (*ab*, *dank*, *entgegen* etc.) or any genitive prepositions (that leaves *bei*, *nach*, *mit*, *für*, *von*, *zu*, *unter*, *aus*, *an*, *in*, *auf* and *über*)
3. If you add a compound before a preposition that starts with a vowel you need to put an *r* as in *daRüber*, *woRan* etc.

Resources that helped me to learn *da-/wo-* compounds:
http://www.nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/wodakompositaexpl.html
http://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Da/Da.html

Comment: Thank you @thekeyofgb. It's a bit clearer but I think I need to just read and listen more to be able to fully understand. Extra thanks for the link to to the LSA site :)

Answer (score 6):

CreeperNation, thank you for that delightful brain teaser.

There's a memory aid to illustrate the difference:

> Womit? Damit! (*What* with? With *that*!)

As a first approximation, you can read *da-* as *that-*, and *wo-* as *what-/where-*.

I can't help thinking of the difference in terms of programming language constructs. Both prefixes serve as a backreference to something already established or implied by context. The da- prefix corresponds to a pointer to an object, the wo- prefix is an interrogative on top of that, like calling a function method of a pointed-to object. I hope this makes some kind of sense... (I wonder if it would still make sense to me if I'd re-read in a few weeks)

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't fully understand the programming example...I mean I know a little bit (a very little bit) about programming but not too much. Although I like the 'womit, damit' aid :D

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the other usages explained in @thekeyofgbs answer, the wo- compunds can also be used to replace the relative pronoun in sentences.

> Das Buch, **über das** wir heute sprechen = Das Buch, **worüber** wir heute sprechen
>
> Das Handy, **nach dem** ich suche = Das Handy, **wonach** ich suche

Comment: @Jan Corrected.